# jquery click stop working after view load with layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

I have a click bind to an element in an external JS File:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $(document).on("click", "#loginRegisterLink", function () {
        $("#loginInfoPanel:visible").hide();
        $("#loginWindow:hidden").show();
    });
});
```

This code in the Layout Shared CSHTML:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/Presenter/Account/loginheader.presenter.js"></script>
```

When the home page is loaded, the code works fine, but when I navigate to another View using the same Layout that includes this script, the click function don't fire anymore, why?

Note: When the JS file is loaded in the second view through the Layout file, I get "Status Code:304 Not Modified" from the browser.

Thanks.

Comment: are you sure element has same ID and same script included? Are any errors thrown in console when other view loads? Really not enough information given to be able to troubleshoot

Comment: Hi, I get no errors. As the code is included in the _Layout shared View file, the code remain the same for every Views that I load.

Comment: something has to be different for code not to work. Impossible to tell what is causing it without being able to inspect both in browser console

Comment: what information do you need?